# How to apply/loop the same function to a group of similar objects in R

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, visualization

I have a big datatable, containing metadata such as different drug treatments to samples under different conditions and numeric features of measurements.

Mini dummy dataset:

```
#I only used one sample here for simplicity. You can image there are multiple sample IDs
#and sometimes the same ID but different timestamp. 
#for each sample, the sample will have 3 levels conditions, 
#for each treatment(here's only 1, R), multiple dosages per condition
#on top of the condition&dose there is next layer to have combo or not.
#from id ~combo they are factors or at least I believe so
#after all these, the real measured variables V1,2.....

set.seed(123)
id <- rep("S112",30)  
timestamp <- rep("T4",30)
condit <- rep(c("uns","2S","3S"), 10)
treatment <- rep("R", 30)
dose <- rep(c("0.1","1"),each=15)
combo <-rep(c("none","I10","I100"),each=10)
v1 <-rnorm(30,0.5)
v2 <-rnorm(30,0.05)
v3 <-rnorm(30,0.1)
df <- data.frame(id,timestamp,condit,treatment,dose,combo,v1,v2,v3)
```

now if I can visualise the one treatment of R, at different condition and different dosages and even combination.

```
#import libs
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(wesanderson)  #I have great movie taste I know

# now I look at treatment of interest
R <- df[df$treatment=="R" & df$combo == "I10",]

#table to long
R_long <- gather(R,7:9, key = bin, value = value, -id, -timestamp, -condit )
#plot it
b<- ggplot(R_long, aes(x=bin, y=id,fill=value))
pal <- wes_palette("Zissou1", 100, type = "continuous")
R_map <- b + 
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=pal)+
  facet_grid(dose~condit)+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 40,face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=35, face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"))+
  xlab("Bins")+
  ylab("Sample ID")+
  ggtitle("Plot of treatment R")

  ggsave(R_map,file="R.pdf",width=30,height=30)
```

This works, but I want to perform the same thing to a group of drugs in the real dataset, instead of just one treatment R. I'm guessing the vectorised R language should allow something like group the treatments I want in a vector c(R1, R2, R3, R4) and apply the above code on this vector. How could I achieve that?

Note: I'm sorry for this poorly worded question. I honestly am too basic in R to even ask the key questions. So feel free to help me edit this (the COVID part is for the good spirit)

Thank you

Comment: Do you want a single plot for treatment R1-R4 together?

Comment: Hi @ava I would love to have separate graphs. Sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: I see. My answer below will generate separate graphs.

Comment: @ava thank you for helping! Sorry I just finished working and got home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `map` or `map2` from `purrr`

Here an example with `map2` that would allow you to add another variable from a vector, such as combo:

```
library(purrr)

#get data
set.seed(123)
id <- rep("S112",30)  
timestamp <- rep("T4",30)
condit <- rep(c("uns","2S","3S"), 10)
treatment <- rep("R", 30)
dose <- rep(c("0.1","1"),each=15)
combo <-rep(c("none","I10","I100"),each=10)
v1 <-rnorm(30,0.5)
v2 <-rnorm(30,0.05)
v3 <-rnorm(30,0.1)
df <- data.frame(id,timestamp,condit,treatment,dose,combo,v1,v2,v3)


# make function if you use map, just remove y from the function and replace y with a variable within the function definition
makeplot <- function(x,y) {

# get data
R <- df[df$treatment==x & df$combo %in% unlist(strsplit(y, split="|", fixed=TRUE)),] #allows or statements in the vector
R_long <- gather(R, 7:9, key = bin, value = value, -id, -timestamp, -condit)
# make plot
pal <- wes_palette("Zissou1", 100, type = "continuous")
R_map <- ggplot(R_long, aes(x=bin, y=id, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal) +
  facet_grid(dose ~ condit) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 40, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 35, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm")) +
  xlab("Bins") +
  ylab("Sample ID") +
  ggtitle(paste("Plot of treatment", x))
ggsave(R_map, file = paste0(x,"_",paste0(gsub("|","_",y,fixed=TRUE)), ".pdf"), width = 30, height = 30) 
}

#make vectors, the function above allows you to combine combos with |
treatment <- c("R","R","R")
combo <- c("none","I10","none|I10")

#apply
map2(treatment,combo,makeplot)
```

PS: I hope that your research will aid finding an effective off-label treatment for COVID-19 patients.

Comment: hi ava thank you for your support. I'm a web lab scientist working in drug screening on cancer. But we did submitted a grant for covid antiviral.  I'm testing the code. I have a few questions: 1)I didnt quite understand the y in the function (x.y) , this related the to the #getdata unlist(strsplit(y, split="|", fixed=TRUE), what does this bits intend to do, aka why I need to split a string Y? I think this part affects the combo<- c("none|I10")

Comment: the idea of this function is so I can type in all the drugs I want to see in the treatment <- c("R","R","R"), and combination in combo <- c("none","I10","none|I10"). But I also need to look into the dosage. so I think I need to incorporate that in to get data in the function. Does that blow the function from fun(x,y) into fun (x,y,z)? I'm sorry I'm terrible at this/

Comment: Sry just finished my shift at the hospital. The `y` in the function was just to give an example, how more variables can be added. `strspilt` was used to allow subsetting if combinations of `y` were entered in the function using `|`. Yes, you could add another variable with `z`, however, `purrr::pmap` is probably more convenient if you use more than 2 variables. It is probably the best to open a new question and clearly state how the function should work and how the graphs should look like.

Comment: don't be sorry. I totally understand that and thank you for taking your time. I just got back from hospital as well, spent 12 hrs there to process patient samples. Thank god I can still call a burger delivery. Let me play with the code, if I screw up again, I'd send you a message. Take care :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already `facet`ed, you can't go that direction, but if you want one drug per loop, then wrap it in a `for` loop:

```r
for (tr in unique(df$treatment)) {
  R <- df[df$treatment==tr & df$combo == "I10",]
  R_long <- gather(R, 7:9, key = bin, value = value, -id, -timestamp, -condit)
  #plot it
  pal <- wes_palette("Zissou1", 100, type = "continuous")
  R_map <- ggplot(R_long, aes(x=bin, y=id, fill=value)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal) +
    facet_grid(dose ~ condit) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 40, face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 35, face = "bold")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm")) +
    xlab("Bins") +
    ylab("Sample ID") +
    ggtitle(paste("Plot of treatment", tr))
  ggsave(R_map, file = paste0(tr, ".pdf"), width = 30, height = 30) 
}
```

Comment: thank you. I have some problems. The code gave me an error message -x : invalid argument to unary operator.  This for loop out to find all the unique treatments in the entire dataset with combination "I10", so I can control what combination I want to see, which is brilliant. A problem is the dosage treatment itself. Presumably this loop will take all the dosages of each treatment in the data set right? if so then the output graph wont tell me which dose is which graph, they will all be under same treatment name?

Comment: My ***guess*** on your error (since I cannot reproduce it) is that your real data has a treatment that does not include a combo of "I10". But I don't know, since the code works with the dummy data. I don't understand your point about dosage, though: `dose` is one of the facets (labels along the right side), so it is certainly there. When I look at one such plot, I see `0.1` and `1` on the right-side facet labels. Is that not indicating which dose is for which graph(s)? Each whole plot is one treatment name, so they are organized together.

Comment: oh yes, you are right on the dosage. I take that question back.

Comment: about the error message still. Indeed some treatments dont have the I10 combo, but even when I switched combo to "none", which means only treatment alone, I still got the same error message... I can see the unique(df$treatment) is getting the correct list of treamtments....

Comment: If some treatments do not have a combo of `"I10"`, then perhaps after `R <- df[...,]` you can include `if (!NROW(R)) next` (which will not produce a plot for zero-data and will continue with the loop). Otherwise, your mention of `combo == "none"` (or whatever you meant) suggests you have other intentions for your loop. Do you mean to iterate over every combination of `treatment` and `combo` programmatically?